# Loading Data from an excel File using Spark Java Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-excel

I want to load data from an Excel file in HDFS using Spark Session 2.2. Here is bellow my Java code and the exception I got.

```
Dataset<Row> df = 
            session.read().
            format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
            option("location", pathFile).
            option("sheetName", "Feuil1").
            option("useHeader", "true").
            option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").
            option("inferSchema", "true").
            option("addColorColumns", "false").
            load(pathFile);
```

I got this exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.close()V
>       at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.com$crealytics$spark$excel$ExcelRelation$$getExcerpt(ExcelRelation.scala:81)
>       at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$inferSchema$1.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:270)
>       at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$inferSchema$1.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:269)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.inferSchema(ExcelRelation.scala:269)
>       at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.(ExcelRelation.scala:97)
>       at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:35)
>       at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:14)
>       at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:8)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a dependency issue. Check if in your pom/sbt some of libraries don't use different version of  Apache POI. You can do it for instance with mvn depenency:tree (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) or appropriate SBT/Gradle... command.

When you find the conflicting dependency (the one where Workbook.close() method is missing), you can exclude it from the import.

Apparently the `close()`method was added here: https://github.com/apache/poi/commit/47a8f6cf486b974f31ffd694716f424114e647d5

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: for spark-excel, it only supports scala.
So if you want to use this dependency, you can compile your scala code to .jar package, then use this package in your java project.